# Mystery ImportFile reference?

Tags: c#

I inherited a project with the following reference in one class: "`using ImportFile"`

I can 't see a references folder to see which files are referenced by this project. Where can I see what file/assembly ImportFile points to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace may be split over several different assemblies. I would locate the namespace in the Object Browser and examine the types that it includes. There you can see in what assembly each type is declared.

Example of what it can look like with such a namespace (I have my Object Browser set up to list namespaces on the top level, rather than Assemblies):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open the Object Browser (shortcut Ctrl+W, J). Make shure you have browse: "My Solution" selected at the top. then in the search bar in the top type in ImportFile. This will now show you the ImportFile namespace. Clicking on each element on the left will make the bottom right corner show the assembly that class is in, It could be more than one.